# Best way to visualise timing of seasonal events?

Tags: seasonality, recurrent-events, data-visualization

I have a spreadsheet in which I track various seasonal event – first snow, arrival of migratory birds, that kind of thing. You can view it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lyw5X_6ra4WX4qX3qGARx3Ol5AVcCcM699KqJw7MmQQ/edit#gid=0).

What I would love to do is be able to visualise – as I get more data over several years – those events happening earlier or later in the year.

Honestly, I can't even quite picture what an ideal visualisation would be! Any suggestions on how to get an overview of the shifting annual timing of these events would be greatly appreciated.

Some specifics:

- The order of the events might change, year to year – sometimes the swifts will arrive before the poppies bloom.
- I'd like to be able to add new events into the mix – maybe I'll recognise our first lamb as a new event, but one for which I won't have historical data.
- The overall idea is to be able to answer the question: "did event X happen early or late this year, and to what degree".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend plotting each event separately, using a dotchart over the days of the year.

[image: season]

This shows you immediately that the one event we have a date for in both years ("Swifts leave") happened on the same day in both years. Once you have a few years' worth of data, you can see typical variability or trends.

You might want to restrict the horizontal axis for each plot. No need to show November and December for "First tree blossom", while "First processional caterpillars" could already happen in the previous year.

If you are interested in whether different events flip orders, you could show multiple events in the same plot, using different colors for the different events. Just don't overdo it - if you try showing all 18 events using18 colors, you will run out of colors and end up with something incomprehensible. Instead, group maybe 3-5 events that are related. If you do so, I would stagger them vertically slightly above and below the "year" lines.

R code below:

```
dates <- data.frame("2017"=c(rep(NA,11),"2017-08-01","2017-09-01","2017-09-16","2017-09-18","2017-10-01","2017-10-17","2017-12-01"),
    "2018"=c("2018-01-01","2018-02-23","2018-02-25","2018-02-27","2018-03-10","2018-04-05","2018-04-06","2018-04-08","2018-04-08","2018-04-21","2018-07-22","2018-08-01",rep(NA,6)),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rownames(dates) <- c("First processional caterpillars", "First tree blossom", 
"First bee", "Heavy dump", "House martens", "Swallows arrive", 
"Swifts arrive", "First tic on Cilla", "First barbecue", "First poppy", 
"No snow visible on the mountains", "Swifts leave", "Swallows leave", 
"Can see snow on the mountains", "Cool enough to dry hair with a hairdyer ", 
"Mushrooms abound", "Purple jumper on", "River Gavressa frozen")

Sys.setlocale(locale="US")
opar <- par(mfrow=c(6,3),mai=c(.5,.5,.5,.1))
    for ( ii in 1:nrow(dates) ) {
        plot(as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-12-31")),c(0.5,ncol(dates)+0.5),type="n",yaxt="n",main=rownames(dates)[ii],xlab="",ylab="")
        axis(2,1:nrow(dates),2016+(1:nrow(dates)),las=1)
        abline(h=1:nrow(dates),lty=2,col="lightgray")
        index <- which(!is.na(dates[ii,]))
        points(as.Date(paste0("2017",substr(dates[ii,index],5,10))),index,pch=19)
    }
par(opar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have more data (more years), consider a spaghetti plot (google images can show many examples). This would be a high-level complement to @Stephan Kolassa's answer. It will show all of the individual things you're tracking at once with a line for each. You won't be able to differentiate individual lines that well, but that's not the point. Instead you will be able to see if the general trend is showing things moving up earlier or later in the calendar over time (I assume that's what you're anticipating).